# How to release ViewModel when the View is closed?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Our current application wraps each `View` into one `Window` (this is only a prototype application). And each `View`/`Window` has one `ViewModel` assigned as DataContext. Now my question, what is the practice to release the `ViewModel`, when the `Window`/`View` is closed?

I tried to handle the Closed event of `Window`, and set the DataContext to NULL. My ViewModelBase class implement IDisposable interface. But when I am debugging, I find out that the Dispose() function is not called. And when I am using memory profiler, I see the `ViewModel` is never released.

So what is the correct practice to release `ViewModel`

UPDATE:

Two potential memory leak sources:

1. I am using `IEventAggregator` to do event pub/sub. I am using `EventAggregator` class from Prism 4.1, but and simply wrap it in a Singleton class (which implement IEventAggregator interface because we don't want to use Dependency Injection yet).

And inside `ViewModel`/`View`, I just use (code in VB.NET)

```
_ea.GetEvent(Of MyEventType).Publish(MyEventObject)
_ea.GetEvent(Of MyEventType).Subscribe(AddressOr MyEventHandler)
```

1. I am using some ActiveX controls. The one I am testing is using PivotTable from OWC (Office Web Component). And I admit I didn't know how to handle such control in MVVM world. I normally have `ViewModel` hold a member of such control directly, which I think breaks the rule of MVVM, and it is also the reason currently I can only do hard-coding of wiring `ViewModel` in the code-behind of `View`.

For example, in the code-behind, I have such line:

```
Me.DataContext = New MyViewModel(Me.pTable)
```

to initialize the `DataContext`

And in the constructor of `ViewModel`, I normally do two things:

a) setting/changing (in constructor or functions) properties of `ActiveX` control like this:

```
Me.pTable.DisplayDesignTimeUI = False
```

b) handling the events from `ActiveX` Control

```
AddHandler pTable.DblClick, AddressOf DblClickHandler
AddHandler pTable.SelectionChange, AddressOf PivotTableSelectionChangedHandler
```

I admit this "letting ViewModel handle ActiveX control" usage doesn't seem to be good to me. But those controls are necessary to us.

Comment: Are you assigning the DataContext as a hard-reference in Code (myView.DataContext = new ViewModel();) or are you providing it via Binding? A Binding should allow the ViewModel to get removed, the first one might be problematic. Still handling Closing-Event should work. Any Singletons all VMs use?

Comment: I had the same thing and resolved it by having the VM inherit from an interface that specified a delegate for close events.

Comment: @Gope For some `View` (and the one that I am testing), I am indeed using the hard-reference in code-behind (the ultimate goal is to remove this practice, but currently we have to use it). And yes we do have some singletons in `ViewModel`. Some `ServiceLocator` and `EvengAggregator` which we simply implemented using Singleton. How does it affect the reference?

Comment: @Gope and to make it worse, the root path I see from memory profiler, which might prevent the memory to be released, is linking to some .net ActiveX control (which VM has as member). It may a mess but that's the only wy I found to handle such Controls

Comment: @GayotFow is it a good idea for the VM to directly handle such event? Because we might change the code in the future so there is no Close event/`Window`, only `UserControl` in certain regions

Comment: For the EventHandling: Frameworks like CaliburnMicro use a simple Class (WindowManager et al)where they attach view/control events to the given viewModel when putting the two together which works quite good...
Some more info: https://github.com/Gope/M3 and http://goo.gl/4vArGa (look at the bottom)

About the References. An EventAggregators Lifecycle is usually the same as the Apps lifecycle meaning all VMs reference the Aggregator.  Are the Aggregator Subscriptions WeakRefs? Otherwise the Aggregator will be holding the VMs. At least the ones handling any messages...

Comment: the VM should not hold the ActiveX Control. You can often get around such problems by using a Converter. This sounds a little strange at first but one example can be a Converter that instantiates UserControls when used inside a ContentPresenter. Like that it might help do all the ActiveX-Stuff inside the View-Area, without having the viewModel reference it and also keep it outside the direct view code.

Comment: @tete, the VM does not handle the *event* per se.  It receives a POCO notification that allows the VM to clean up and gracefully die.

Comment: @Gope 1) I didn't even know EVentAggregator can hold the VM. All I do is something like _ea.GetEvent(Of MyEvent).Subscribe(AddressOf MyHandler). Is it a problem? 2) Could you give me some example of using Converter with ActiveX? Because it sounds nice but I honestly don't understand how to do in detail. Thanks!

Comment: Which EventAggregator Implementation are you using? Prism? Usually you register VMs for specific messages. To deliver this message (methodcall) you need a reference to the VM inside the Aggregator. This Reference can be stored regular (hard-Ref) or via a WeakReference which can be garbage-collected. (it is just one possibility for your problem, not too likely though)

Post some code for the activeX thingi. I will try to show you some converter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, too much comments. I believe that the Aggregator is no Problem. PRISM will probably use WeakReferences for the Subscribers, while the VMs use the static field to Access the EventAggregator when publishing (right?). This should be fine as the GarbageCollector does collect instances with references to static objects.

The ActiveX-Control could be more of a problem. Are you setting many properties or just a few? Then you can create a Control holding the ActiveX-Control. Define DependencyProperties for each setting you need to do and bind those to the viewModel. In the DP-registration insert ChangedHandlers. As soon as you set a value in the viewModel its transfered to your control and you end up in the changehandler for the property where you can set the submitted value at the ActiveX-Control (value is in the EventArgs.NewValue).

The Converter is only usefull if the creation of the control is not so simple. Then put a ContentPresenter in your XAML. Bind the Content to Whatever (leave it blank, etc.) and put in a Converter (IValueConverter) that returns an instance of the ActiveX-Control.

Hope that helps you

Comment: Thanks! I guess I understand the first method (exposing the properties of ActiveX control by defining `DependencyProperty` and binding to corresponding properties in `ViewModel`), even though we actually have dozens of such properties. But before I decide to use this method, I actually have one crucial question: Is there any particular reason that it is a bad thing to have VM have a ActiveX control? I mean, except for the fact that it breaks the MVVM rule to have a View-related component in VM so it makes it hard to do unit-test. Since creating those `DependencyProperty` is a tedious job

Comment: So I need to evaluate whether it is worth of doing that. BTW I actually found out the memory leak source. I needed to call `Dispose()` function in both the ActiveX control and the WindowsFormsHost object to remove the event handlers. But still I am interested in your proposal since this ActiveX twist with VM has always bothering me.

Comment: Just inbetween: noone is saying that you can't have one property doing all configuration. Make the type of the DependencyProperty a KeyValuePair<enum,object> f.e. and then set it to new KVP(MySettings.Height, 10.0)... just as an idea

Comment: Great that you found the leak though! :)
For the other question: UnitTesting is the most important reason imho. The MVVM rules are pretty simple: Extract the logic out of the view and put in into a helper-class and maybe a model (if needed). This is not a pattern. It's an architectural style, meaning do what works for you, but keep in mind how others do it so you don't run into the wrong direction.

Comment: That is true (to have one property do all configuration)! And in fact most of those properties in ActiveX control won't get changed so there is no need to have VM expose one property for each corresponding one in ActiveX control. I'll embrace this method

Answer (score 1):

I'll post my direct solution to this problem. But for long term run, I think Gope's solution is better since it complies with MVVM design.

Gope is right that the problem was because `ActiveX` control is holding a reference to my `ViewModel` (even though it is the `ViewModel` who has a `ActiveX` control member). My problem is actually the same as in this post [Cleaning up WindowsFormsHost in a WPF dialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2741d762-f430-4b30-abbf-2b8cb4a24aa9/cleaning-up-windowsformshost-in-a-wpf-dialog?forum=wpf). I needed to call `Dispose()` function of the `WindowsFormsHost` object to release the host. I also called `PivotTable.Dispose()`to release the `ActiveX` control itself (in fact I tried the `PivotTable.Dispose()` at first and the `PivotTable` object was released but the host was not. So then I added the Dispose function of the host). Now when I verify with memory profiler it seems my `ViewModel` and `PivotTable` are released correctly.